# Convert whole number float values in Pandas column to int, while keeping non-whole float numbers intact?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a column of float values in a Pandas data frame like so:

```
df['nums'] = [100.0, 35000.00, 42639.25, 552.27]
```

And I want to convert whole number floats like `100.0` into integer data type.
I know I can access the last two digits of the list using `str(df['nums'][1])[-2:]` which should print `'.0'`.

I tried something like:

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1):
    if str(row[0])[-2:] == '.0':
        row[0] = row[0].astype(int)
    else:
        continue
```

Of course, this doesn't work in the slightest. How can I iterate over this column in a way that it can convert every whole number float into an int while keeping non-whole number floats intact? `df['nums']` would look like this:

`df['nums'] = [100, 35000, 42639.25, 552.27]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to cast the floats and integers? There may be an easier way depending on what the end goal is.

Comment: Because Series can only have a single dtype, the only way to do what you want is to have the column upcast to `object` as the `int` dtype cannot hold a float and you wont get `1` as a float... IMO this is not a good option so *why* is it imperative to have `100.0` stored as `100` and not the float `100.0`?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I have to work with concatenating these numbers to a string, and if the float decimal is 0 then the concatenation won't yield the result I need. It's very peculiar, but I need to have it this way.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh your response was just what I needed. Thank you for your time.